# How many ways are there to write 18 as the sum of 4 distinct positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I know that you can just do casework and find all of the cases, but is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146482/the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer-as-the-sum-of-distinct-parts-with