# Probability of sum of 6 picked integers from [1..36]

Tags: probability

How we would calculate probability that sum is bigger than 92.5 if we pick 6 random numbers from [1..36] ?
Not putting them back (if took 1, then we can pick [2..36] etc.

I cannot think of how to put this because there are lot of variations of how this can fall. Unless to write some script.

Comment: I'm a little confused! [1..36] are the integers from 1 to 36? If yes then you can find the number of possible answers to the inequality $x_1+x_2+...+x_6 \ge 93$ where $1 \le x_i \le 36$, then subtract the number of answers where each $x_i$ is not unique.

Comment: " [1..36] are the integers from 1 to 36? " yes. I am not even sure how can I solve this equation :)

Comment: Then I have to write a very very, very, long answer.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I only know about generating function which produces the answer with aid of computer. It may be easier to calculate the answer using script, without using any combinatorical or generatingfunctionological technique. The number of ways to choose six distinct numbers whose sum is equal to or lower than 92 is denoted as $S(92)$:
$$S(92)=[x^{92}y^6]\dfrac{1}{1-x}\prod_{k=1}^{36}(1+x^ky)$$

where $[x^{92}y^6]$ indicates the coefficient of $x^{92}y^6$, and the total number of ways to choose six distinct numbers is
$$N={36 \choose 6} $$
Thus, the desired probability is $$\dfrac{N-S(92)}{N}$$

This particular question is quite complex yet widely known. I found a past post where more general question was answered. This is the link:

[The number of ways to write a positive integer as the sum of distinct parts with a fixed length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146482/the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer-as-the-sum-of-distinct-parts-with)

The following generating function is probably more useful, so I quoted it from the above link.

> Let $q(n,k)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct
>   parts. The generating function is $$Q_k(x)=\sum_{n\ge
> > 0}q(n,k)x^n=\frac{x^{k+\binom{k}2}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\dots(1-x^k)}\;.$$

Comment: If you want to get an exact solution, you definitely need script or aid of computer. But you may be able to get an approximate answer not by relying on them.

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of the two variable generating function! So the probability is $$\frac{1517196}{1947792}\approx 0.778931220582074$$ which agrees with my simulation.

Comment: Thanks for verification. If you're interested in this sort of generating function, I recommend http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

Comment: Thanks, I have that book! But I think I could not make sense of the formula when I saw it before, this problem serves as a good example for that. Thanks again!

Comment: I did not analyze those formulas because turned out that I just needed to find middle sum and so that bigger sums have 50% probability and smaller sums have 50 % probability. That sum is 111, we calculated this way - take smallest sum - 1+2+.. +6 and biggest sum possible: 31+...+36, add those sums and and divide by 2. So we get 111 is the middle. SO bigger or smaller than 111 has less than 50% each. Then I ran script to find out how many combinations are possible to get 111 of 6 numbers in [1..36], different places counts, and I got 23136480. But thanks for post :)

Comment: And it is likely that I got ok number, because the other man calculated probability, and then we have in database 20K rows sample of those random data and probability was very well matching or real sample.